# VBO and PolygonMode lines

Tags: opengl

I am currently trying to draw lines with polygon mode LINES. I have been able to do this sucsessfully many times with immediate mode. But now I am trying to do this with VBOs and can not figure out why.

Here is a sample of the code. As far as I can tell all of the offset, blending, and color methods work fine but It will not draw lines unless I do GL_LINES under glDrawArays.

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINES);  
glLineWidth(3.0f);
glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
glPolygonOffset (-5.8f, -1.0f);

glEnable (GL_BLEND); 
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 3 << 2, 0L); 

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count /* elements */);
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);   
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
```

Comment: have you checked for gl errors ? you're using the wrong enum: GL_LINES instead of GL_LINE

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm glad it ended up being something so simple.. I have always been very confused as to when to use GL_LINES and when to use GL_LINE. What is the difference? EDIT: what do you mean by 'check gl errors'? Like with a debugger or something?

Comment: If you have a newer version of OpenGL, you might support `ARB_debug_output` AND/OR `KHR_debug`. Those extensions are like `glGetError (...)` on steroids; they bring much needed verbose debug info to GL without having to use a third-party tool. Only took 20 years ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were using GL_LINES instead of GL_LINE. If you are unsure about which enum to use, just check the documentation and it will give you a list of possible values. If you want more help with debugging your app, try calling glGetError ( http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) after every opengl call, that way you will be able to see the function where the error appears and then you can just google that.